# Propper way to do logging on windows

Tags: python, windows

I am using PySide (Python3 and Qt) for a native GUI which runs on ms-windows.

Up to now I opened a file in `tempfile.gettempdir()` and use this for logging.

But I guess there is a more appropriate way to do logging on windows.

Comment: Define "appropriate" or this is unanswerable. What qualities are you expecting from a logging system? Also, why just "windows"? How is it specific to Windows?

Comment: Did you look into python's eponymous `logging` module btw?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev since I do not use windows and have little no to experience on this plattform, I just ask if there is a common sane default way, which I just do not know yet. I was hopping that there is such a way. Logging to a file in the `tempfile.gettempdir()`, but it feels strange.

Answer (score 0):

Logging in Windows is just the same as on any other platform. The only OS-specific feature is the suggested logging location: it's `%TEMP%` or `%LOCALAPPDATA%\<your_app>` subtree (or `%APPDATA%\<your_app>` if for some reason you wish the logs to be copied across systems if the user has a [roaming profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roaming_user_profile)).